# list give another list, each item in list give another list, need to record in excel

Tags: c#, excel, list, html-agility-pack

I have a problem of iterating lists, and lists and lists, they are nested means each list cell contains another list:

here is the problem:

my excel file which contains paths of pages, i need to add more cells under 
these cells:

```
**admin/myPage.asp**

*add--> admin/myPage1.asp
add--> admin/myPage2.asp
add--> admin/myPage3.asp*

**admin/Dir/myPage.asp**

*add--> admin/Dir/myPage1.asp
add--> admin/Dir/myPage2.asp
add--> admin/Dir/myPage3.asp*
```

i searched this page: admin/myPage.asp, used htmlAgilityPack, found all links,
    pages, redirects on this page,

```
pages found:
 *admin/myPage1.asp
 admin/myPage2.asp
 admin/myPage3.asp*
```

need to note them under this page in excel,

then these pages also to be searched for further links:

```
pages found:
*admin/myPage1.asp
 admin/myPage2.asp
 admin/myPage3.asp*
```

if more links found then note them also

then search those pages,

until no further page found.

i am stuck here:

in nested lists how to iterate each list and 
then found new list, then iterate this new list,
then find other list then iterate this list,

then come back to previous lists which have items pending.

how to do it in c#

---

background:
i have a list of paths, like this, "admin/start.asp", in excel, there are hundreds 
of like this, i get them in list, and then loop over each path, each path 
has page in it, on each page i have to extract all paths using HtmlAgilityPack, 
and then the paths from this page are searched and get more paths from these pages,
 until no more paths found in these pages, i have to keep on searching, but i have to
 record them also in excel. any body have idea:

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var allListItems = new List(firstList);
for (int listItemIndex = 0; listItemIndex < allListItems.Count; listItemIndex++)
{
    allListItems.AddRange(allListItems[listItemIndex].Items);
}
foreach (var listItem in allListItems)
{
    //do something
}
```

With `firstList` being the list you start from.
This will basically do a breadth search by adding all the nested lists to `allListItems` and iterating through them. This works because `allListItems.Count` is recalculated for each iteration.
Afterwards you can just iterate through all the items and do whatever you want.